# Django templates Could not parse the remainder

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this template, I am looping through all choices in a question, and I want to default check the question user previously selected. selected_choice variable is coming from my view and I got have it ok in my template.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div id="detail" class="">

    <form hx-post="{% url 'main:vote' question.id %}" hx-trigger="submit" hx-target="#detail" hx-swap="outerHTML">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>
            {% if error_message %}<p>
                <strong>{{ error_message }}</strong>
            </p>
            {% endif %}
            {% for choice in question.choices.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" {% if selected_choice and choice.id==selected_choice %}checked{% endif %}>
            <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I get this error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '==selected_choice' from 'choice.id==selected_choice'
```

Comment: You need spaces around the `==`. `choice.id == selected_choice`.

Comment: wow, what an error ‍♂️. Thank you very much @evergreen